# Can I use the command line, or run a batch file from managed code? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

Just like the subject states. I want to be able to run iisreset, batch files, etc. from the a console application. Can I/How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's quite possible, for example:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\listfiles.bat");
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this example from [C# Station](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace csharp_station.howto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Demonstrates how to start another program from C#
    /// </summary>
    class ProcessStart
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process notePad = new Process();

            notePad.StartInfo.FileName   = "notepad.exe";
            notePad.StartInfo.Arguments = "ProcessStart.cs";

            notePad.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
  info.UseShellExecute = true;
  info.FileName = "iisreset";
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);



  Console.ReadLine();
```